# Magento, how to add block inside other block e.g. name="header" block

Tags: magento, block

In my local.xml i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="asdasd" as="asdasd" output="toHtml" template="newblock.phtml"/>
        </reference>    
</default>
</layout>
```

this code makes my block displaying at the bottom of the page no matter what do i put inside 'reference name=" "'

How to generate the block inside specific block which isnt type="core/text_list".
I dont want to make any changes in .phtml files.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just remove `output="toHtml"`  and `call any position` of using  below code

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("asdasd");?>` at `header.phtml` according to your wish postion